# Hierarchical permalink structure for posts showing categories and sub-categories

Tags: categories, permalinks, urls, hierarchical

I'm having a lot of trouble finding an aswer to this. This is what happens to my permalink structure currently:

- When I open the page, filtering all posts for a category, the url is:
  `myblog.com/category/`
- When I open the page filtering all posts for a sub-category the url
  is: `myblog.com/parent-category/child-category`

Both are OK! But...

When I open the page for a blog post listed in a sub-category the url is:

`myblog.com/parent-category/postname`

I need the URL to be: `myblog.com/parent-category/child-category/postname`

But I don't know how to add the proper rewrite rule for this! Any ideas? My current Permalink structure is `/%category%/%postname%/`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you chose category and subcategory from the right options tick boxes when editing the entry. Choose only the subcategory box in every entry and it will show the nested URL.

This is I found online. And I just tried that. It's true. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your permalink structure to default provided by wordpress i.e. myblog.com/sample-post/.
Works for me. Give it a try.